# How to increase memory for a Java application in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, java, virtual-memory

I suppose I should to increase a Java heap size for the application. Does Java heap size have a common settings for all Windows 10 applications? Or should I set it for the application I need. How? What if it's a Java application but it runs as an .exe file?

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on each application, since you can run java from the standard JDK/JRE, or there are different tools which generate `.exe`.

For the standard environment, something like:

```
java -Xmx2048m
```

For help about parameters:

```
java -X
```

See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

But for other packages (`.exe`), usually there is a configuration file, in which you can enter vendor specific parameter, or use the standard parameter `-Xmx2048m` as is.

Comment: Right. There was .ini file with already existing -Xmx command

Comment: Then change its value, and you are good to do.